# How do I execute a Java/Python program multiple times?

Tags: java, python

I am currently working on an assignment, where the task is to measure the execution time for a number of programs in both Python and Java, for the purpose of measuring and comparing performance for the two computer languages. I have 10 tests in total, in sets of 2; for every set, one test is written in Java and the corresponding one is written in Python, and so forth. I want to run every test multiple times, e.g. 100 times, and measure the time for every run. Then I'd like to compute the sum of the obtained execution time(s). How would I do this in Python/Java? I have tried writing a double for-loop like this:

```
for i in range(1, 100): 
for j in range(1, 10000000):
# do integer division
```

...but it doesn't seem to work. Also I'd like to do the same thing in Java. How would I do this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: In particular, "doesn't seem to work" is *not* a problem specification.

Comment: Are you trying to invoke the Java program from Python or vice versa?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. My first post here. No, I'm working in Eclipse IDE where I have both JDK and PyDev installed.

Answer (score 0):

The first item you may want to add is the `time` command, which returns the current time in seconds.  Thus, you can measure a time span like this:

```
import time

for i in range(1, 100):
    start = time.time()
    for j in range(1, 10000000):
        # do integer division
    finish = time.time()
    span = finish - start
    # span is the time in seconds.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import time

for i in range(1,101):
    start = time.time()
    # do your thing
    print(int(time.time() - start))
```

`starts=time.time()` starts the counter. and then `print(int(time.time() - start))` will return the time taken in seconds.

For reference, use `101` in `range()`. the second paramter to `range()` is a "go up to" and not an include

Answer (score 0):

```
            long startTime = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++){
                startTime = System.nanoTime();
                for(int j = 0; j <= 10000000; j++){
                    //Do integer division
                }
            }
            long endTime = System.nanoTime();
            long duration = (endTime - startTime);
            System.out.println(duration);
```

I think that's what i'ts going to look like in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Python:

```
import time

meas = []
for i in range(100):
  start = time.time()
  for j in range(10000000):
    # do integer division
  meas.append(time.time() - start)
```

Java:

```
long meas[] = new long[100];
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
  long start=System.nanoTime();
  for(int j = 0; j < 10000000; j++)
    // do integer division
  }
  meas[i] = System.nanoTime()-start;
}
```

In both languages you will have 100 measurements in the 'meas' arrays (units: whole nanoseconds for Java, floating point seconds for Python - so the latter has fractional part too), where each measurement run the division 10000000 times.